# Is it possible to monkeypatch the args passed to an Angular service similar to $delegate.method?

Tags: angularjs

In my current Angular project, I've been making use of $provide.decorator to monkeypatch some functionality downstream of the main app, and it led me to a question I couldn't figure out. Let's say you were to use this technique to add a "Bloop bloop" message before an $http.get (ignoring for a minute that an interceptor would be better here):

```
$provide.decorator('$http', function ($delegate) {
   get = $delegate.get;

   $delegate.get = function () {
      // arguments passed to $http.get are accessible here
      console.log('Bloop bloop');
      return get.apply(this, arguments);
   }
   return $delegate;
}
```

My question is: how would one get access to the arguments passed to a service itself? In this case, it's possible to call a $http() directly, with 'GET' as a method property. Is there any way to get inside of there, similarly to how it's possible get inside any service or factories methods like the above?

Comment: So why isn't an interceptor applicable? Without explaining *"why"*, this becomes an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: It's really more of a hypothetical. I originally wanted to generalize an end-point pinger that I'd attached to some services, but nearly all of the services that would have benefited called $http() rather than its methods. I ended up going with a different approach: with angular-cache, expiration logic, and a pinging service. But this still bothers me.

Comment: I guess the reason why I didn't go with an interceptor in that case, either, was that I couldn't figure how I would make an $http call, either directly or via the pinger service, without a circular dependency from $httpProvider. I guess I could ask a separate question about that but it would just be another XY problem (ie. how can I call $http from within an interceptor? Does it even make sense to want to do that?).

Comment: Use the `$injector` to lazy-load `$http`.